# How can I find multiple starting areas on a procedural map?

Tags: tilemap

I'm using perlin noise to generate a 2d map, with ground types and natural resources.

When you start a new game I need to place your town hall as well as your opponents in such a way they are on grassland and near natural resources.

For an oversimplification, I have a 2d array of integers where a block of 0s and a couple 1s would be great for starting but anything lower than a 0 would be bad. How can I isolate a few blocks of what I'm looking for, ideally with a distance threshold so town halls aren't next to each other.

How does civilization do this for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding locations that are suitable close to resource can be done using 
[influence maps](http://gameschoolgems.blogspot.com/2009/12/influence-maps-i.html) - data structures that model various relationships with respect to their locations, and typically assume that the impact of these relationships spread outward across space and/or time. (I recall having heard that some titles in the Civilization series use influence maps, bu I don't have a definitive reference for that at the moment)

The core concept of an influence map is that some locations have values which in turn influence the values of the surrounding area. The good news is that they are very flexible & you have a lot of options in terms of their design & implementation. Unfortunately, that's also the bad news - there's so much choice that finding the right balance of features & functions requires a bit of experience or experimentation. Here's a couple of examples based on the situation you've described.

First, we assign some value to the resource locations. I arbitrary picked 5 locations on a 8x8 grid & gave them all the value of 10 as shown on the left. 
Next, the influence spreads, as shown on the right. Since I was doing this all by hand, I simply decreased the value based on [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry), but you can change the metric to suit your needs.

[image]  [image]

The next thing to do is decide how influence is combined from multiple sources. I've shown two options. The one on the left uses uses addition. This is most appropriate for situations where the combined amount of resources is important, for instance, if more ore allows you to get more gold. On the right I used the `max` function; this would be more appropriate when only the distance to the nearest source matters, but additional source don't help.

I've also colored coded things to make them a bit easier to read. For each I picked a threshold & everything at that level or higher, I tinted green.

[image] [image]

From here, you can look for other factors such as masking to include only acceptable terrain. Then consider candidate locations. That part should straight forward. Identifying all location pairs that are at least a minimum distance apart is the really hard part. Often times there are just too many possible combinations to consider, so practice, it tends to be solved stochastically. You randomly pick a location & then see if there's a suitable partner location for the opposing base. Using the [fast Poisson disk sampling](https://www.jasondavies.com/poisson-disc/) techniques might help.

Finally, you need to consider what might go wrong. There's a chance that a given random map might not have a suitable combination of locations. There's also a chance that a few combination exist, but there are some many invalid combinations that you're statistically unlikely to find them. In that case, you need a fall back solution. Some options are:

- generate a new map & try again
- force the current map to have certain features
- relax your constraints & have one or more locations further than desired from the resources

Comment: This was great, thanks.  I got it working!  Ended up keeping track of the highest starting weight, and adding those coords to a list of viable starting nodes.  Then I iterated through the map again, and checked the distance between the next highest nodes with the current viable nodes, and if it's far enough, marked it as viable too.  Great answer!  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

An option is to avoid searching for locations and just force them.

You could place all the starting locations a suitable distance away from each other, and for every location, change the local terrain to grassland and add resource nodes nearby if there aren't enough.